# Pre-labelled LTO-6/LTFS tape numbers- Are the tape numbers stored somewhere on the tape?

Tags: tape, lto

I have some Fujifilm LTO-6 tapes which come labelled with tape numbers. I'm writing a script and I would like to assign a variable from the tape number. Is this information stored anywhere on the tape? If it's not I'll just have to create a variable from an input prompt, but if it is it would be much better.

Comment: I think the chip in the cartridge has a serial number, but it is unrelated to the barcode on the tape.

Answer (score 1):

Every LTO cartridge has a so called MAM-chip (media auxiliary memory). This chip contains a lot of information like the manufacturer, manufacturing date, serial number etc.

There is also a field "barcode". When you use an autoloader that read the barcode and it inserts the tape into a drive it will then update this field.

When you ordered prelabeled tapes, it really depends. If they're factory made you might be lucky and the information in MAM is already set.

You can read the mam chip data using SCSI commands. There is a rudiementary software that can do this on linux: http://github.com/arogge/maminfo

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas has already suggested, you can READ barcode attribute in MAM by `maminfo`. However, this software can not write data to that field.

[This](https://github.com/Kevin-Nakamoto/lto-cm) Linux software can WRITE an arbitrary barcode sequence to that field, depending on your needs. This software is useful for users who ordered non pre-labeled products, and printing barcode by themselves. It is also helpful for users who ordered pre-labeled but there is no pre-written sequence in MAM.

Just as an example, if your barcode sequence is `LTO012L6` then load the cartridge into the drive and invoke:

```
$ sudo lto-cm -f /dev/sg3 -w 2054 -m LTO012L6
```

NOTE that `/dev/sg3` depends on your environment, but it means SCSI device path to your drive. `-w 2054` option means write data to the Barcode field (the address of the field is `0x0806h` = 2054 in decimal). `-m LTO012L6` option specifies barcode sequence which you need to write.

Also, you can verify the written sequence with the same program:

```
$ sudo lto-cm -f /dev/sg3 -r 2054
```

The options are the same idea as that of `write` command above, but `-r 2054` option means reading data from the Barcode filed in MAM.

Comment: What software is that? Did you have something to do with creating it?

Comment: No problem, it's just that the site policy requires [disclosure](/help/promotion) if you're recommending your own product or solution, even if it's free and/or open source.